# return json in python class

Tags: watchdog, python-class

I have this class and function in python to monitor file creation and i want to retrieve the result as json:

```
import win32api
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import json
import time
import watchdog.events
class MyFileSystemEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            print(f"New directory created: {event.src_path}")
            json_data = {
                "event_type": event.event_type,
                "file_path": event.src_path,

            }
        else:

            json_data = {
                "event_type": event.event_type,
                "file_path": event.src_path,

            }

            with open("results55.json", "a") as f:
                json.dump(json_data, f)
                f.write("\n")

        print(f"New file created: {json_data}")
        return json_data
    def get_json(self):
        return self.json_data

# Function to start monitoring the file system
def monitor_filesystem():
    observer = Observer()
    event_handler = MyFileSystemEventHandler()

    # Enumerate logical drives or volumes
    drives = [drive for drive in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split("\x00") if drive]

    for drive in drives:
        observer.schedule(event_handler, drive, recursive=True)

    myevent=observer.start()

    try:
       while True:
             # Continue monitoring until interrupted
               time.sleep(20)
               # pass
               observer.stop()
   # observer.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
           return ('end of monitoring ')

# Start monitoring the file system
monitor_filesystem()
```

I'm calling this class and function  from the main as:

```
 import filecreation as fl
 F_monitore=fl.monitor_filesystem()
 returned_data=fl.MyFileSystemEventHandler.get_json()
 print("the return data1 is R", F_monitore)
 print("the return data1 is",returned_data)
```

I want to get json_data as retrieved value in the main to work on it. when I print it in the console it gives the values but I can't get these values in the main